# Why the console just has this sentence? Hibernate: select max(id) from customers

Tags: java, hibernate

I am new to hibernate and want to program a hibernate one to many project. I can compile it successfully, but the console just have one sentence:

```
Hibernate: select max(id) from customers.
```

Could you please help me find the errors?

1) This is `Customer.java`:

```
    package com.test;

    import java.util.Set;

    public class Customer 
    {

        private Long id;
        private String name;
        private Set orders;

        public Customer(String name,Set orders)
        {
            this.name=name;
            this.orders=orders;
        }
        public Customer(Set orders)
        {
            this.orders=orders;
        }
        public Customer(){}
        public Long getId() {
            return id;
        }
        public void setId(Long id) {
            this.id = id;
        }
        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }
        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }
        public Set getOrders() {
            return orders;
        }
        public void setOrders(Set orders) {
            this.orders = orders;
        }



    }
```

2) This is `Order.java`:

```
    package com.test;

    public class Order 
    {
    private Long id;
    private String orderNumber;
    private Customer customer;

    public Order(String orderNumber,Customer customer){
        this.orderNumber=orderNumber;
        this.customer=customer;
    }
    public Order(){}
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getOrderNumber() {
        return orderNumber;
    }
    public void setOrderNumber(String orderNumber) {
        this.orderNumber = orderNumber;
    }
    public Customer getCustomer() {
        return customer;
    }
    public void setCustomer(Customer customer) {
        this.customer = customer;
    }
    }
```

3) This is `Customer.hbm.xml`:

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping
    PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
    "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">

    <hibernate-mapping>

        <class name="com.test.Customer" table="customers">

            <id name="id" column="id" type="long">
                <generator class="increment"> 
                </generator>
            </id>

            <property name="name" type="string">
                <column name="name" length="15"></column>
            </property>     

            <set name="orders" cascade="save-update" inverse="true">
                <key column="customer_id"></key> 
                <one-to-many class="com.test.Order"/>
            </set>


        </class>

    </hibernate-mapping>
```

4) This is `Order.hbm.xml`:

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping
    PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
    "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">

    <hibernate-mapping>

        <class name="com.test.Order" table="orders">

            <id name="id" column="id" type="long">
                <generator class="increment"> 
                </generator>
            </id>

            <property name="orderNumber" type="string">
                <column name="order_number" length="15"></column>
            </property>     

            <many-to-one name="customer" column="customer_id" class="com.test.Customer">
            </many-to-one>


        </class>

    </hibernate-mapping>
```

5) This is `hibernate.cfg.xml`:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
              "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
              "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
    <hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
    <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:8889/mydata</property>
    <property name="connection.username">root</property>
    <property name="connection.password">root</property>
    <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>

    <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
    <property name="show_sql">true</property>

    <mapping resource="Customer.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="Order.hbm.xml"/>
    </session-factory>
    </hibernate-configuration>
```

6) This is `Test.java`:

```
    package com.test;
    import java.util.HashSet;
    import org.hibernate.Session;
    import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
    import org.hibernate.Transaction;
    import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;
    public class Test {
        public static SessionFactory sessionFactory;
        static
        {
            try
            {
                sessionFactory=new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();//Configuration，sessionFactory are all objects
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                System.out.println("exception occured");
                ex.printStackTrace();

            }
        }
        public static void saveCustomerAndOrderWithCascade() throws Exception
        {
            Session session=sessionFactory.openSession();
            Transaction tx=null;
            try
            {
            tx=session.beginTransaction();
            Customer customer=new Customer("zhangsan",new HashSet());
            Order order=new Order();
            order.setOrderNumber("zhangsan_order1");

            Order order2=new Order();
            order.setOrderNumber("zhangsan_order2");

            Order order3=new Order();
            order.setOrderNumber("zhangsan_order3");

            order.setCustomer(customer);
            order2.setCustomer(customer);
            order3.setCustomer(customer);



            customer.getOrders().add(order);
            customer.getOrders().add(order2);
            customer.getOrders().add(order3);

            session.save(customer);
            tx.commit();
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                if(null!=tx)
                {
                    tx.rollback();
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                if(null!=session)
                {
                    session.close();
                }
            }

        }
        public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
        {
            saveCustomerAndOrderWithCascade();
        }

    }
```

The console just has those sentences:

```
    log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.hibernate.cfg.Environment).
    log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
    Hibernate: select max(id) from customers
```

Does anybody can tell me the reason why it just has this?Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It is because your customer class uses `increment` generator to generate the PK value .

`increment` generator  will issue `select max(pk_column) from table` , then add one to retrieved value . The resulting value is then used as the PK value of the new customer record.

I would use `identity` generator and make sure the data type of the PK column is `AUTO_INCREMENT` .In this way , hibernate will let mySQL to use its `AUTO_INCREMENT` feature to generate the PK value.

Comment: Thank you!I tried your solution,but it still has no sentence.Some one told me that I need to override the equals() and hash code().But I don't know why I need to do that.

Comment: hi Shiying , please check this https://community.jboss.org/wiki/EqualsandHashCode and ask another question if you still don't get of idea of that article.